# Как отловить null в ComboBox.SelectedItem?

Tags: c#, try-catch

Есть кусок кода, который формирует путь по шаблону с добавлением выбранных пунктов. WorkerList - это и есть ComboBox.

```
            string TargetHost = HostBox.Text;
            string WorkDirectory = @"C:\worker\" + SQLget.WorkerName(WorkerList.SelectedItem.ToString()) + "\\";
```

Далее идёт кнопка, которая по нажатию, в директорию копирует файлы и ставит задание. Если ComboBox пуста - я поймаю нулРефЭкс, что справедливо.

Своими граблями я так и не дошёл, почему не отлавливается в catch. Что сделал:

```
        private void TaskButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // Кнопка на вкладке планировщика. Размещает задания на сбор базы и ёё копирования.
    {
        try
        {
            string TargetHost = HostBox.Text;
            string WorkDirectory = @"C:\worker\" + SQLget.WorkerName(WorkerList.SelectedItem.ToString()) + "\\";
            SetState.CreatTask(TargetHost, WorkDirectory, true);
            SetState.CreatCopyTask("ещё больше аргументов");
        }
```

Далее я пробую так:

```
            catch (Exception) when (IndexerList.SelectedItem.ToString() == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Пусто!", "Ошибка");
        }
```

Но, как вы поняли из темы, не взлетело.

Пробовал добавлять в тело трай такую фигню(сам нутром чую, что бред какой-то)

```
                if (IndexerList.SelectedItem == null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("Выберите индекс");
            }
```

Так как у меня два поля(TextBox, ComboBox), я хочу чтобы на каждое незаполненное поле ловить своё исключение. В случае catch-when как у меня, событие не вызывается.
Можно смело тыкать носом в главу учебника или или в msdn, где будет описано как отладить. Кармический монплезир гарантирую.

Comment: Проверяй значение `String.IsNullOrEmpty (String)`, сперва получив стринг, а потом уже создавай таск если стринг не пустой.

Comment: И `SelectedItem` может не быть [равен нулю](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Когда `IndexerList.SelectedItem` равен `null`, в конструкции

```
try { }
catch (Exception) when (IndexerList.SelectedItem.ToString() == null) { }
```

валится `NullReferenceException`, вот здесь: `when (IndexerList.SelectedItem.ToString() == null)` Поэтому в этот блок `catch` ты никогда не попадешь.

Правильнее делать так:

```
try { }
catch (NullReferenceException) when (IndexerList.SelectedItem == null) { }
catch { }
```

А еще лучше, вообще не провоцировать ексепшн, а вместо этого делать простую проверку:

```
private void TaskButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HostBox.Text == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Пусто!", "Ошибка 1");
        return;
    }

    if (WorkerList.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Пусто!", "Ошибка 2");
        return;
    }

    // дальше делаешь, что хочешь...
}
```

Comment: `if (WorkerList.SelectedItem == null)` не сработает, он не равен нулю, а содержит ссылку на объект последнего выбора, null только в начале инициализации, до выбора, надо где то запоминать состояние, `Observer*` чего то использовать разумно. И брать по событию из него.

Comment: Все сработает, читай поставленный вопрос: "я хочу чтобы на каждое незаполненное поле ловить своё исключение". Незаполненное поле в `ListBox` - это и есть null. Кроме того, `null` в `SelectedItem` может быть не только после инициализации, но и в процессе существования (например, если удалить выбранный элемент, или если реализовать возможность сбрасывать выделение).

Comment: @Groxan Спасибо. Как раз вчера доковылял, что зря я .ToString() в combox пытался к bool подтянуть. В итоге сделал два катча на exception, с двумя when для cmobobox и textbox. А в вашем нет ошибки? `HostBox.Text == null` - это ведь стринг, он же всегда не null. Тогда уже так `HostBox.Text == ""` И почему не надо провоцировать эксепшен? Потеряю другие возможные ошибки?

Comment: Наверное, я бы не назвал это ошибкой, но и рабочим кодом тоже не называю. Это всего лишь шаблон, который показывает, как заменить ексепы. `string` может быть `null`, поэтому стринг правильнее проверять так: `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HostBox.Text))`. Любые ексепы - это потеря производительности, поэтому, если есть возможность обойтись без них, то лучше так и делать.